# Hiding/Showing divs on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a script that when a button is clicked it displays all of the content beneath it and hides the other buttons content. The only problem I'm having is that I want to refactor the script *so it only works if you hit the button*, instead of the entire div the button sits in as it's causing some confusion. What would be the best way about this?

```
<div class="signup-button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
  <div class="signup-form" style="display:none;">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="signup-button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
  <div class="signup-form" style="display:none;">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="signup-button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
  <div class="signup-form" style="display:none;">
    Content
  </div>
</div>

<div class="signup-button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Subscribe</button>
  <div class="signup-form" style="display:none;">
    Content
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
(function($) {

  $(".signup-button").on('click', function() {
    $(".signup-button").not(this).find(".signup-form").hide();
    $(this).find(".signup-form").toggle("slow");
  });

})(jQuery);
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/v6bmphct/3/

Comment: change that very first `.signup-button` in your jquery to `.signup-button button` and you should be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to attach the event listener directly to the descendant button element. In doing so, the `click` event isn't triggered when clicking on the other content. You would also have to change instances of `$(this)` to `$(this).parent()` or `$(this).closest('.signup-button')`.

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/4dhs969a/)

```
$(".signup-button .btn").on('click', function(e) {
  $(this).parent().find(".signup-form").toggle("slow");
  $(".signup-button").not($(this).parent()).find(".signup-form").hide();
});
```

Alternatively, since `event.target` is a reference to the clicked element, you could also just check to see if `event.target` is the button element by using the `.is()` method:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/eghcs76u/)

```
$(".signup-button").on('click', function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('.btn')) {
    $(this).find(".signup-form").toggle("slow");
    $(".signup-button").not(this).find(".signup-form").hide();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
(function($) {

  $(".signup-button").find('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings(".signup-form").toggle("slow");
    $(".signup-button").not(this.closest(".signup-button")).find(".signup-form").hide();
  });

})(jQuery);
```